# Getting interval Monday-Sunday in SQL BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the data between last weeks monday and last week sunday. I'm having trouble with getting the relative part. I'm trying like this:

```
where date <= LASTWEEKSUNDAY OR  date >= LASTWEEKMON
```

The closest I got to what I seek was using now(), but it returned also some days from the current week. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you running this code and when are you running it? Once a week, or every day? Have you tried the `BETWEEN` syntax?

Comment: Its running in real time using Bigquery. I tried with BETWEEN, but could't manage to make it work

Comment: How are you defining `LASTWEEKSUNDAY`?

Comment: as DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(SUNDAY))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's what you want

```
where date between DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(SUNDAY)), interval 6 day) and DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(SUNDAY))
```

You shouldn't use OR in the where statement, it'll cover all the days if you use OR. Instead, you can prefer using AND or between.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing:

```
where date >= date_sub(date_trunc(current_date, week(Monday), interval 1 week) and
      date < date_trunc(current_date, week(Monday))
```

Although the function calls change, the same logic works on `datetime`s and `timestamp`s.

Of course `week(Monday)` is the default for `isoweek`, so you can use:

```
where date >= date_sub(date_trunc(current_date, isoweek, interval 1 week) and
      date < date_trunc(current_date, isoweek)
```